# Unable to run Sphinx as a Windows Service

Tags: configuration, windows-services, sphinx

Sphinx was running as a Windows Service for the last several months until this morning.  When looking into the log files, I continue to get this error:

FATAL: binlog: log open error: failed to open ./binlog.001: No such file or directory

I can run Sphinx via the command line as follows:  searchd.exe

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why Sphinx ran as a Windows Service all this time, I do not know.  In order to get it to run now, I had to explicitly define the binlog location.  Once that happened, the Sphinx Windows Service began working.

Comment: The folder needs to exist, to be 'able' to write it. Seems like the 'current directory' when starting the service, didnt exist (or was not writable), so it couldt write the binlog (to this non existant directry!)